# Pods are stuck at ContainerCreating after deletion of the pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to delete my pod with force deletion with the following command

> kubectl delete pods my-pod-fg4ss --grace-period=0 --force

but my pod is recreating

> my-pod-fg4ss     0/3     ContainerCreating            0          2d3h

I am unable to delete the pod

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes pod gets recreated when deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686151/kubernetes-pod-gets-recreated-when-deleted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely this pod is part of a Deployment. In Kubernetes, when you have a deployment resource it needs to have a minimum of 1 replica so that's why when you delete a pod it automatically creates a new one.

In order to delete the pod, you have to actually delete the deployment:

```
kubectl get deployments
```

Get the name of the deployment (probably "my-pod") and delete it:

```
kubectl delete deployment <name>
```